# error in ...what? bug hunting

Tags: debian, debug

I use debian testing. Two weeks ago I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade` on my desktop as usual. Unfortunately, a major league bug has been occurring since then. I did a few upgrades more later in the belief that this would fix the problem. My difficulty lies in examining which package caused it.

I saw the bug for the first time when I opened `chromium` one reboot after the dist-upgrade. Chromium showed its window and immediately killed the X server. Same thing happened with `google-chrome` but only when entering certain websites (!). The bug seems to affect blender too. The difference is that it doesn't kill X, it just gives me

```
glibc detected blender: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007fe28000c100
```

and memory map.

I hoped that downgrade will help, but changing version of `libpthread` changed nothing and changing `libc6` isn't easy. I would like to make sure what the source of this behaviour is rather than blindly experimenting.

How should I examine the situation?